# Qt OpenGL Rendering text issue QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, rendering

I'm using [QGLWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qglwidget.html#renderText-2) and this code to draw a text on the screen but the rendering is catastrophic if the string's length is too high : [image: text rendering issue]

Here's my code :

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
QString qStr = QString("Here's a very long string which doesn't mean anything at all but had some rendering problems");
renderText(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, qStr);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: `renderText` is not a function that I am aware of from any library. If it's from a library, then tell us which one. If not, then provide the code for it.

Comment: Just edit my post with source.

Comment: renderText() is part of the OpenGL API inside the Qt framework. You can deduce that based on the fact it takes a QString as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when using ***Helvetica***. Changing the font to ***Arial*** solved it.

I did a small wrapper around it to make things easier:

```
void _draw_text(double x, double y, double z, QString txt)
{
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    qglColor(Qt::white);
    renderText(x, y, z, txt, QFont("Arial", 12, QFont::Bold, false) );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> This function can only be used inside a QPainter::beginNativePainting()/QPainter::endNativePainting() block if the default OpenGL paint engine is QPaintEngine::OpenGL. To make QPaintEngine::OpenGL the default GL engine, call QGL::setPreferredPaintEngine(QPaintEngine::OpenGL) before the QApplication constructor.

Hence, have you tried to use `QPainter::beginNativePainting()` just before the call, and `QPainter::endNativePainting()` just after?

Also, note that the text is rendered in window coordinate, not taking into account at all your current OpenGL matrix state (in short, your `glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1)` call has no effect). You can see in the implementation [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/opengl/qgl.cpp#line4920) that they save your current OpenGL state by calling `qt_save_gl_state()`, then create their brand new matrices with:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then draw the text, and finally restore your previous OpenGL state with `qt_restore_gl_state()`